# C++ - How to create an instance of a class with changing name

Tags: c++, pointers, graph, nodes

A little background... I am working on a simple maze game. Essentially, the program is to take a text file in the following form:

```
A * B * *
B * C * A
C G D * B
D * * * C
E I F * *
F J G * E
G * H C F
H * * * G
I * * E *
J * K F *
K * L * J
L * * * K
```

where the first character is the current node, the second character is the node to its north, the next is the node to the east, then south, then west. Each line represents a node and the 4 nodes that it can connect to.

the game is text based where a player starts at node A and may move in one of four directions (N/E/S/W). for node A, the only legal move is east to node B, and then from there the player could either move east to node C or move west back to node D. at node C, the user could then move north to node G, and so on and so forth. anywhere there is a *, there is no node in that direction (so i'll set to NULL)

i'm still in the relatively early stages of programming this and this is my first assignment where i've needed to use nodes, or even classes, so i want to make sure i have a good grasp on how to tackle the game before i get into the meat of the programming.

the actual playing of the game i think will be pretty simple. my issue is setting the game board up. i understand how to create file streams and read in the characters.

```
int BuildGraph()
{
    ifstream build;
    build.open("file.txt");
    char tempChar;

build >> tempChar;

while(tempChar != '\n')
{
    for(int a = 0; a <= 4; a++)
    {
        switch (a)
        {
            case 0:
                Node tempChar; // NEED HELP HERE
                                    build >> tempChar; // Grabs the next character
                break;
            case 1:
                // set Node.north to tempChar
                break;
            case 2:
                // set Node.east to tempChar
                break;
            case 3:
                // set Node.south to tempChar
                break;
            case 4:
                // set Node.west to tempChar
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

my question is how do I create a node and name if off the character that is being read? in this case, the first node should be A, a.east should get set to B, and a.south, a.north, and a.west should all be set to NULL.

how do i accomplish this in this format? is there a different, simpler, or just better approach i should be taking?

i should also note that i'm using a class, called Node, that is currently set up like this:

```
    class Node()
{
public:
    char *node_north = ;
    char *node_east = ;
    char *node_south = ;
    char *node_west = ;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a Node like this:

```
struct Node {
    char name;
    char north;
    char east;
    char south;
    char west;
};
```

And a vector to keep the nodes in

```
std::vector<Node> nodes;
```

And read it like this:

```
Node node;
build >> node.name >> node.north >> node.east >> node.south >> node.west;
nodes.push_back(node);
```

Or you could have a node like this:

```
struct Node {
    char north;
    char east;
    char south;
    char west;
};
```

and a map of nodes

```
std::map<char,Node> nodes;
```

and read it like this:

```
char name;
Node node;
build >> name >> node.north >> node.east >> node.south >> node.west;
nodes[name] = node;
```

Comment: @sakau2007: After you read the node you will need to store it -- maybe to a std::vector<Node>.

Comment: I see how you added the name field, but I'm not sure how this helps me. wouldn't only the last node's information be saved?

How would I reference the members?

The way I was thinking was node.A.north (would return NULL) node.A.east (would return node B, or char B depending on how I set it up; I think returning the whole node, and thus the directional pointers would be best)

Comment: @sakau2007: you can have a function which goes through the nodes and finds one with a particular name, or maybe use a `std::map<char,Node>`.

Comment: @sakau2007: I've added some detail to my answer

Comment: i guess my next question is what exactly is this line of code: std::map<char,Node> nodes;

where is it placed in the program, and what is it functionally doing? also, any special include statements that i need to insert to get this to work other than iostream and fstream?

Comment: I've got this portion working almost as desired. Thanks so much for your help to this point

However, I'm still confused on how my individual nodes are saved, and once they are, how are they referenced (node.A.south, A.south, something else...?)

I think my confusion comes into play around here:

nodes.push_back(node);


I assume this is taking the information we have stored in the node and "pushing" it to something, but I don't know what.